# Date change automatically in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please find below is my code written in server.js file which i am learning newly . Everything is working good but i want a javascript function that automatically changes date the next day. Kindly help with the script

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
//Java Script page to make one Common HTML Page
var profiles={
 'About':{
 title:'About Me|Hariharan.V',
 heading:'About My Profile',
 Date:'Sep 23,2016',
 content:  `  <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. </p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>`
},
'MyEducation':{
    title:'My Education|Hariharan.V',
heading:'About My Profile',
 Date:'Sep 23,2016',
 content:  `  <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. </p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>`
},
'MyExperience':{
    title:'My Experience|Hariharan.V',
 heading:'About My Profile',
 Date:'Sep 23,2016',
 content:  `  <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. </p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>`
},
'MyCertification':{
    title:'My Certification|Hariharan.V',
 heading:'About My Profile',
 Date:'Sep 23,2016',
 content:  `  <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. </p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>
              <p> This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content. This is a content.</p>`
}
};


    function CreateTemplate(data){

        var title= data.title;
        var Date=data.Date;
        var heading =data.heading;
        var content=data.content;
   var htmlTemplate=
                  <html >
                      <head>
                        <title>
                       ${title}
                        </title> 
                         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
                         <link href="/ui/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                      </head>
                      <body>
                           <div class="container">
                              <div class="row">
                               <a href='/'> Home</a>|
                              <a href="MyEducation">My Education</a>|
                           <a href="MyExperience">My Experience</a>|
                           <a href="MyCertification">My Certification</a>|
                          <hr/>
                           <h3>
                           ${heading}
                              </h3>
                          <div>
                              ${Date}
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            ${content}
                          </div>
                         </div>  
                      </body>
                  </html>
                  `;
return htmlTemplate;

}
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'index.html'));
});
app.get('/:ProfileofHari', function (req,res){
    //ProfileofHari= The content of First Page (About)
    //profile(ProfileofHari)=The content object of About
    var ProfileofHari=req.params.ProfileofHari; 
    //Index in the profile object
res.send(CreateTemplate(profiles[ProfileofHari]));
});

app.get('/ui/style.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'style.css'));
});

app.get('/ui/Hariharan.png', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'Hariharan.png'));
});
var port = 8080; // Use 8080 for local development because you might already have apache running on 80
app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log(`IMAD course app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Comment: You may use moment.js (see http://momentjs.com)

Comment: @Stephan Could you please brief me

Comment: moment.js makes date manipulation easy in javascript.